# Background color during a flip horizontal animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've been looking for a way to change the black background color during a flip horizontal animation, but so far, nothing did the trick for me.

[This is what it looks like right now](http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/8117/blackbackgroundf.png)

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me! Here is the code that I've been using for the animation:

**ViewController.h:**

```
-(IBAction)howitworksbutton:(id)sender;
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
-(IBAction)howitworksbutton:(id)sender 
{
      howitworks *secondview = [[howitworks alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      secondview.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
      [self presentModalViewController:secondview animated:YES];
}
```

I also created a new UIViewController subclass called 'howitworks'.

Regards, Ivar

Answer (score 5):

Try and set the background color of the window object of your app delegate:

```
YourAppDelegate   *delegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[delegate window] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

I believe this is the main background color that sits behind all of your application views.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Slee! Should I put this piece of code in the AppDelegate.m file? And then create an applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Comment: you could just go into your app delegate code and set it there

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks Javy! I think I already tried this, but maybe I put it in the wrong place. Where exactly should I put this? I'm new to Xcode, so sorry for all these stupid questions.

Comment: You can place it in viewDidLoad, and it should be okay.  I haven't seen the rest of your code, so Slee's answer may (or may not) be more appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code didn't work. I've tried adding Slee's code, but that didn't work either. Maybe it's just not possible? Thanks again for all the help Javy!

Comment: Click your MainWindow.xib file and set it's background color to black.  That might do it.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking. He doesn't want to change a view's background (technically he does but it's the rootview's container). See Slee's post for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:**

open file`AppDelegate.swift`

inside function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

add **`window?.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor("#EEEEEE")`**

---

**something more:**

`hexStringToUIColor` is a helper method, you can use your way to create `UIColor`

```
func hexStringToUIColor (_ hex:String) -> UIColor {
    var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```